# What is the technology behind Windows Azure REST Api?

Tags: .net, rest, azure

I am curious about how the Azure REST Api is built.  Did Ms use the Rest Starter Kit or the WCF Web.API? Or are these SOAP services exposed over HTTP bindings ?

Comment: Unless someone from Microsoft is willing/allowed to share we'll never know.

Comment: It never hurts to ask :)

Comment: True. I was just predicting that it would be nearly impossible to get an answer.

Comment: Strongly agree with Erno :)
@Robotsushi, you might have better chance for an answer in the reletead Azure forums on MSDN, but I really doupt you'll ever get a public answer for that ;)

Comment: I expect it's ruby on rails :¬)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we've ever shared that detail on implementation.

Answer (score -1):

The table services API most likely uses WCF Data Services or some customized variant of it.  The other APIs probably use .Net 4 WCF REST.  They certainly don't use REST starter kit because it was only ever a prototype.  And Web API is still in development so I know they don't use that.

Comment: How do you know how table storage is implemented? :-) The protocol is OData, but I don't know that it's safe to assume we implemented the server using that specific .NET library. (I honestly don't know the answer.)

Comment: @smarx  This page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179423.aspx says that you can use the .Net client library for  WCF Data Services library to access Table services.  If it isn't implemented using WCF Data Services, then it is going to be a very close approximation, considering how tightly coupled that client is!

Comment: There are also client libraries in PHP. Does that mean we implemented the server in PHP? :) My point is that the protocol doesn't necessarily dictate the implementation.